# Disappearing Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched on the internet to see if I can find any references to these problems without success.

Occasionally, in Excel 2016 or Excel 2019 I open a macro-enabled workbook and discover all macros within the file have disappeared.   This is despite enabling the macros when the workbook is opened.  I determine there are no macros available by selecting Macros on the Developer Tab.  No macros will appear in the macro dialog box.  In addition, although a number of macros are linked to buttons within the file, I will try to use these and none will work.

If I save, close and re-open the workbook in either of these versions of Excel the macros still do not reappear.  However, if I re-open the file in Excel 2010 the macros are available with all working as intended.  If I save the file in Excel 2010, close it and then reopen it in Excel 2016 or Excel 2019 the macros will have reappeared.

Occasionally, and again in Excel 2016 or Excel 2019, when I open one of my more complex, macro-enabled files it will not open correctly and instead Excel indicates it is corrupted and requires repairs.  I do not allow Excel to make the repairs and instead close the file, reboot Excel and try reopening the file.  Again, Excel will indicate the file is corrupted and attempt repairs which are not accepted.  However, if I switch to Excel 2010 and open the same file no problems are encountered with the file opening normally.  Once it has opened, if I then save the file in Excel 2010 and close it, the file will then open normally in Excel 2016 or Excel 2019.

Might you have an answer to why this is happening?

Comment: When you open a file and there are apparently no macros do you open the VBA editor to look for them?

Comment: Yes, no macro code will appear when I do this in Excel 2016 or Excel 2019.  However, if I open the file in Excel 2010 the macros will be visible in the VBA editor.  It's only when I have done this, and then saved the in Excel 2010, will they re-appear in the VBA editor in Excel 2016 or Excel 2019.  The macro code disappearing in Excel 2016 or Exce2019 is not consistent.  It seems to happen occasionally without any pattern.   But when it does, this is the only way I have found to get the macro code to re-appear in the VBA editor.

Comment: Sorry I can't see what the cause is. The only thing I can suggest is that it's a conflict of different versions of VBA. Can you decide to either always use Excel 2010 or never user Excel 2010?

Comment: If I can find out why this problem is occurring I can abandon Excel 2010.  However, it is Excel 2010 which is allowing me to restore the macros within the file.  I cannot use Excel 2010 exclusively as my clients are using Excel 2016, Excel 2019 and Excel 365.  However, perhaps your suggestion there is a conflict with different versions of VBA within Excel 2010 and Excel 2016 and Excel 2019.  Might you have a suggestion where I could resource these differences to see if I need to change the code within the file?